# Both DIMMs failed. Motherboard fault?

Tags: boot, memory, motherboard, hardware-failure

Both DIMMs on my system failed more or less simultaneously, resulting in a system which would not POST. (Users were complaining it wouldn't reboot unless they hard power-cycled it, for about a week before it wouldn't boot at all). Removing one DIMM, and then the other, failed to resolve the fault. After disconnecting all peripherals and a PSU swap also failed, I replaced the motherboard. The new one also refused to POST! Finally, testing the DIMMS in a different system revealed the dual failure (either DIMM wedged this other system, even though it had a good DIMM present on the other channel).

My question is whether there is any plausible single motherboard fault, which can destroy both DIMMS at once? Has anyone else experienced a dual failure such as this with two-channel memory?

I guess its safest to regard this motherboard as a DIMM-destroyer, at least until a "useless" sacrificial 0.5Gb or 1Gb DDR3 module crosses my path.

The motherboard is (was) a Gigabyte N3050N-D2P, low-power integrated Intel N3050 CPU. The manual says its memory architecture is two banks of one, which is why I find this failure rather surprising.

Comment: "Has anyone else experienced a dual failure such as this with two-channel memory?" - *In the past I have experienced a failure like this.*  "The manual says its memory architecture is two banks of one, which is why I find this failure rather surprising." - *The manual is correct.  Looking at the motherboard, it has a single dual channel DDR3 configuration, this means its physically limited to having only 2 DDR3 installed (besides the fact its literally not possible to install more then 2 DDR3 modules on motherboard with only 2 DDR3 sockets).*

Comment: Be sure the single module you installed was placed in `DDR3_1` instead of `DDR3_2` otherwise your system won't boot.  Besides seeking other people's experience do you have a question?  What is far more likely is the modules simply failed.  *It happens.*

Comment: Question is as stated in paragraph 2, aimed at people who understand hardware design more than myself. Yes, I'm sure that the single DIMM was in the correct single-DIMM socket, and I have since established that *both* DIMMS are failed. If this is not a really freakish coincidence I will have to modify my fault diagnosis technique.

Answer (score -1):

Your question probably has more than one answer.
Here is mine though I am not sure what is "no POST".
If this means that computer powers on, fans are working, but no video or speaker beeps, then it is what I had with my computer.
I was told that it is 99% that I need to clean contacts on my RAM. Since I did this my computer works fine.

Comment: This would be better served as a comment due the commentary surrounding your own confusion about the question.  If you do not have enough to answer the a question, without submitting commentary to it, because your unable to submit commentary you should find another question to answer.  This might sound harsh, but answers like this will be deleted by the community, since commentary like this answer does not actually answer the question that was asked.  If your suggestion is to clean the contacts on the modules, you should state that, and only that since doing so would be an actual answer.

Comment: OK, I am ready to delete my answer by myself if question owner thinks my answer is worth to be only a comment.